# std::function With Member Function For Timer C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I have A timer class that I have set up to be able to bind to a free floating function using the `std::function` template. I would Like to modify the class to be able to support using both free floating functions and class member functions. I know that `std::function` can bind to a member function using `std::bind` but I am not sure how to set this up with the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>

namespace Engine {
    template<class return_type,class...arguments>
    class Timer{
        typedef std::function<return_type(arguments...)> _function_t;

    public:
        Timer(size_t interval,bool autoRun,_function_t function,arguments...args){
            _function = function;
            _interval = interval;
            if (autoRun) {
                Enable(args...);
            }
        }
        ~Timer(){
            if (Running()) {
                Disable();
            }
        }
        void Enable(arguments...args){
            if (!Running()) {
                _running=true;
                enable(_interval, _function, args...);
            }
        }
        void Disable(){
            if (Running()) {
                _running=false;
            }
        }
        std::atomic_bool const& Running()const{
            return _running;
        }
    protected:
        void enable(size_t interval,_function_t func,arguments...args){
            _thread =std::thread([&,func,interval,args...](){
                std::chrono::duration<long long,std::nano> inter(interval);
                auto __interval = std::chrono::microseconds(interval);
                auto deadline = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                while (_running) {
                    func(args...);
                    std::this_thread::sleep_until(deadline+=__interval);
                }
            });
            _thread.detach();
        }
    protected:
        _function_t _function;
        std::atomic_bool _running;
        size_t _interval;
        std::thread _thread;

    };

}
```

Any suggestions would be great. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine, and appears able to bind to member functions. why do you think there's a problem?

Comment: @MooingDuck when I declare the timer `Engine::Timer<void> f(16667,true,Engine::SceneManager::Update);` like that where `Engine::SceneManager::Update` is the member function I get the error "Call to non static function without an object argument"

Comment: The function is `&Engine::SceneManager::Update`, and the first parameter is a pointer to a `SceneManager` to call `Update` on.  This is a question about `bind`, not about your code.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c6335d4f94b9f93 (though it isn't running as expected and I don't know why)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for all of your help. The issue with the time units is just a matter of me not cleaning things up yet, I plan on adjusting it. After looking at the code you posted I got it to bind. As far as the disable function. What would you suggest to fix the race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a member function to this, pass a pointer to the unbound member function (`&Engine::SceneManager::Update`), and then the first parameter is a pointer to the object who should have the member called (a pointer to a `SceneManager` object, this is the "hidden" `this` pointer). This is how *bind* works, so no changes are needed to your code.  As a simple alternative, pass a lambda.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c6335d4f94b9f93 (though it isn't running as expected and I don't know why)

---

Also, I'm confused by the fact your code takes interal as a size_t, then converts it to nanoseconds, then converts that to microseconds, and then uses it. Why not just use microseconds the whole way through?

Your destructor has a race condition.  Disable should stall until the thread has finished executing. I haven't used `std::thread` much, but I'd guess one place to start is `if (_thread.is_joinable()) _thread.join();`  As part of this, it might be useful to have the thread only sleep for 100ms at a time or so, and periodically check if it's supposed to be shutting down.

`Enable` should stop the existing thread, before starting a new one. Better yet, reuse the same thread.  Unfortunately, there's no easy way to have an existing thread switch tasks, so it's easiest to simply `Disable` and then keep your existing code.

Comment: How would you recommend to prevent the race condition?

Comment: @AlexZywicki: Detailed those bits a little more.

Comment: Thats just what I did to fix it actually. I changed the door to `if (_thread.joinable()) {_thread.join();}` and then removed the line `_thread.detach()` which prevented the joining of the threads.